# Avoiding copy when passing an Eigen::Ref to another function

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a throughout my codebase functions that take arguments of type `const Eigen::ArrayXd &` and in order to efficiently wrap these functions with pybind11 and/or nanobind, I need to instead have `Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXd>&` at the python <-> C++ boundary for data exchange. But what I have learned through experimentation, is that passing a `const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXd> &` to a function that wants a `const Eigen::ArrayXd &` always creates a copy. I have some timing results below (the copying code is many orders of magnitude slower). I don't see why the copy is required, and I would like to be able to throw (or at least be warned) if such a copy is being made.

More generally, I would like this code to not copy, and recommendations for how to avoid the copy without modifying the function `foo`. Is it a bug that copies are being made? It seems to me that if the memory block is not being modified (everything is const), no copy should in principle be required.

```cpp
#include <catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp>
#include <catch2/benchmark/catch_benchmark_all.hpp>

#include <Eigen/Dense>

TEST_CASE("Time Eigen copying"){
    auto foo = [](const Eigen::ArrayXd &x){
        return x[3];
    };
    auto bar = [&foo](const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXd> &x){
        return foo(x);
    };
    
    Eigen::ArrayXd a = Eigen::ArrayXd::LinSpaced(1000000, 1, 2);
    const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::ArrayXd> b = a;
    
    BENCHMARK("foo(a)"){
        return foo(a);
    };
    BENCHMARK("foo(ref(a))"){
        return foo(b);
    };
    BENCHMARK("bar"){
        return bar(b);
    };
}
```

yielding the results:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bench_EigenRef is a Catch2 v3.0.0-preview.4 host application.
Run with -? for options

Randomness seeded to: 3293564162

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time Eigen copying
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/ihb/Documents/Code/xxx/bench_EigenRef.cpp:6
...............................................................................

benchmark name                       samples       iterations    estimated
                                     mean          low mean      high mean
                                     std dev       low std dev   high std dev
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
foo(a)                                         100          1070      2.889 ms 
                                        26.4022 ns    26.0969 ns    27.1884 ns 
                                        2.28764 ns   0.684344 ns    4.19932 ns 
                                                                               
foo(ref(a))                                    100             1    384.512 ms 
                                        3.89065 ms    3.87928 ms    3.90858 ms 
                                        71.3259 us    49.9853 us    126.239 us 
                                                                               
bar                                            100             1    380.192 ms 
                                        3.87231 ms    3.85994 ms    3.89631 ms 
                                        84.5487 us    53.4453 us    157.822 us 
                                                                               

===============================================================================
```

Comment: `"big"_a.noconvert(), // <- Don't allow copying for this arg`

https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/eigen.html#failing-rather-than-copying

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem